# SQL Conditional Order By

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am doing a join on two tables. One is a user's table and the other a list of premium users. I need to have the premium members show up first in my query. However, just because they are in the premium user table doesn't mean they are still a premium member - there is an IsActive field that also needs to be checked.

So basically I need to return the results in the following order:

- Active Premium Users
- Regular and Inactive Premium Users

Right now I have it as the following:

```
SELECT Users.MemberId, PremiumUsers.IsActive FROM Users
LEFT JOIN PremiumUsers ON PremiumUsers.UserId = Users.Id
ORDER BY PremiumUsers.IsActive DESC
```

The problem with this is that it places non-active premium members above non-premium members.

(I'm using MS SQL Server 2005 for this)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(PremiumUsers.IsActive, 0) DESC
```

That will group the NULLs with not-actives.

Answer (score 12):

try ORDER BY CASE

```
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN PremiumUsers.IsActive = 1 THEN 1
    WHEN PremiumUsers.UserId IS NULL THEN 2
    ELSE 3
END
```

Comment: I can't believe I never thought to try that ... nice tip!